# How to stub external javascript libraries when writing Rails integration tests/specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shared-libraries, geocoding, vcr

My app interfaces with Google Maps for geocoding and Stripe for payments.  Using [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) I've mocked all requests to these services, which works great.  But the libraries for both are still being loaded in `javascript_include_tag`s.  What's the best way to deal with this so that integration tests can run completely disconnected from the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stub the javascript, then why record the interactions in the first place? Am I missing something?

I'm pretty sure geocoding from a test is a violation of the google maps ToS. I think what you want to do is stub the geocoding itself.

Have never used Stripe, but I might take this approach: add a method in a spec helper to cache the Stripe javascript locally, i.e., when a connection is available, download the Stripe javascript. Then in your view load the javascript locally if Rails.env.test?.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution these days, there is a nice gem called [Puffing Billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy).

Similarly to how [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) allows you to record and replay external requests made by your server code, this library allows you to do the same for external requests made by your client code.